# Pandas Function to Add Underscore to all Column Headers in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, function

I am looking to write a pandas function that adds underscores to the beginning of all column headers of a given data frame.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)

Works even if the original column labels aren't strings.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1]], columns=['a', 0, 'foo'])
#   a  0 foo
#   1  1   1

df.add_prefix('_')
#  _a _0 _foo
#0  1  1    1
```